# How is data from a Bluetooth keyboard handled by Linux? (how does it become a keystroke?)

Tags: linux, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth keyboard that is not functioning properly (further description below) and I'm trying to debug why.

What I've done so far:

- Connected the device using `bluetoothctl`
- In `/var/lib/bluetooth/{adapter_MAC}/{keyboard_MAC}` I've noticed that `Class=0x000540`.  I've looked this up in https://www.question-defense.com/tools/class-of-device-bluetooth-cod-list-in-binary-and-hex and found that it is indeed a `Keyboard` class.
- I've run `btmon`, and I can see the data coming in from the keyboard (see a sample below)

What is happening:

- When a key is pressed on the keyboard, there is no output in the textbox (exception below)
- When a key is pressed on the keyboard, I have been able to see the data coming in through `btmon`
- Occassionally (and I've had some trouble reproducing this, but it seems to be linked to letting the Bluetooth keyboard idle for some time), the first key that I hit is picked up and entered continuously into the textbox / terminal.  For example, if I typed `abc`, then `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`.. may get entered into the terminal continuously, until I press  a key on my wired keyboard.

In `btmon`, when I type `abc` I can see the following 6 messages:

```
a1 01 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00  # a
a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  # keyup
a1 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00  # b 
a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  # keyup
a1 01 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  # c
a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  # keyup
```

My question is: **How is this data handled by Linux and converted into keystrokes?  What is the next step?  Where are the drivers that handle this?**

This is a Fedora-based distro.

Comment: "not functioning properly" isn't very specific.  Is it _sometimes_ working?  Some keys work?  Wrong characters produced?

Comment: @StephenHarris occasionally, if I don't touch the keyboard for a while, then enter some keys, the first character I entered *might* be entered many many times on the screen (e.g. if I typed `hasdlkfjasdlkfjwe` it will sometimes enter `hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh`.. continuously until I hit a key on my wired keyboard).  I haven't determined exactly when this behavior occurs but it seems to be related to leaving the keyboard idle.  other than that, no output for any keys

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information; thanks.

Comment: @StephenHarris updated as requested

Comment: FWIW, this _feels_ like a timing issue; your device has powered down, connects, sends a signal... and the stack drops one of the messages because it's not fully sync'd.  But that's just a guess :-)  Thanks for updating the question, maybe someone else can give a better opinion!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I think my Bluetooth keyboard (AnnePro2 P1, made in China) is mix designed to work only a few centimetres away from the host device. That is it only works with the laptop-in-front-of-you scenario.

My problems are:

1. the keyboard disconnecting randomly and
2. sometimes when the keyboard is "connected" the keystrokes doesn't come through; and
3. sometimes a keystroke is transmitted repeatedly, similar to your description.

Since I have to use a tower PC, I used a USB extension cable to put a Bluetooth dangle to only a palm's distance away from the Bluetooth keyboard and then both problems are gone.

I hope you can change the title of the question. Currently, the title is your diagnosis, which could be wrong; it should be your problem (i.e. "Bluetooth keyboard unresponsive or output characters repeatedly")